# Debugging in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, debugging

Is this possible to debug the query in SQL Server 2005. I have heard about debugging support in SQL Server 2008. Also about debugging of stored procedures, but not about queries yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to have some kind of TSQL object in the database to debug to accomplish this. Since an ad hoc query doesn't directly correlate to a server object, there is nothing to point the debugger at. There also might be a small big of [setup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0fk6z6e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) involved before you can actually start debugging those objects.

However, it if fairly easy to wrap sql statements into a procedure just for the sake of debugging if you have the proper rights. It would not be a good idea to do on a production server, but if you do not have stored procedure creation rights, you might still be able to create a global *temporary* stored procedure, solely for debugging purposes.

Examples:

```
--SQL to test
DECLARE @test DATETIME
SELECT @test = GetDate()
SELECT @test
```

--SQL wrapped in procedure just so it can be debugged
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure  --(or ##testprocedure for global temp procedure) 
AS 
DECLARE @test DATETIME
SELECT @test = GetDate()
SELECT @test

Article illustrating some sql debugging info and examples in use - [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102846/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051607-1.aspx).